# Problema de carregamento de função Node socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('chat/index');

        var io = app.get('io');

        io.on("connection", function(socket) {
            console.log("Usuario Conectado");
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
                var userdata = socket.handshake.session.userdata;
                msg = userdata.name + ' : ' + msg;
                io.emit('chat message', msg);
            });

            socket.on("setName", function(name) {
                var msg = 'Usuario ' + name + ' Conectado';
                var userOnline = {
                    'id': socket.id,
                    'name': name
                };
                io.emit('chat message', msg);
                io.emit('user online', userOnline);
                socket.handshake.session.userdata = {
                    'id': socket.id,
                    'name': name
                };
                socket.handshake.session.save();
            });

            socket.on("disconnect", function() {
                var userdata = socket.handshake.session.userdata;
                if (userdata) {
                    var msg = 'Usuario ' + userdata.name + ' Desconectado';
                    io.emit('chat message', msg);
                    io.emit('user offline', userdata.id);
                    delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
                    socket.handshake.session.save();
                }
                console.log("Usuario Desconectado");

            });
        });

    });
};
```

Toda vez que a função `app.get('/'` é executada cria uma nova conexão `io.on("connection"`. Isso está gerando varias conexões a cada acesso. Existe alguma maneira de abrir a conexão fora da função `app.get('/'`?

Answer (score 0):

*Não testado* mas você pode tentar se conectar fora do `get`, algo assim:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    let io = app.get('io');
    io.on("connection", function(ret) {
        let socket = ret;
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // uso do socket aqui
```

Comment: já avia tentando isso antes mas ele retorna o seguinte erro: io.on("connection", function(ret) {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: Significa que o `app.get('io');` não está funcionando (ou é assíncrono).